# Reason for PermGen OutOfMemoryError when "No GC root found"?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, permgen

I fix 3 different `PermGen` `OutOfMemoryError` issues in webapp and it survives any number of redeploys (I don't try larger then 30) in restricted `-XX:MaxPermSize=66m`. Running application takes ~55 MB of `PermGen`.

Main reason to fix memory leaks is to practice and to make development environment more pleasant - with `<Context reloadable="true">` after compilation my webapp have been redeployed after 3 sec!

Just now I have found error in `catalina.out`:

```
Dec 26, 2015 5:28:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor run
SEVERE: Unexpected death of background thread ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]"
```

As usual I run `visualvm` and run OQL:

```
select unique(map(heap.objects('java.lang.ClassLoader'), 'classof(it)'))
```

and review `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader` instances. What I actually do can be described by OQL:

```
filter(heap.objects('org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader'),
                    'it.state.name.toString() == "DESTROYED"')
```

That one instance doesn't freed `PermGen` memory. But when I invoked *find nearest GC root* I get **No GC root found**.

What is the reason for `PermGen OutOfMemoryError` when `No GC root found`?

Is that possible that reason for `OutOfMemoryError` is processing application requests during redeploy?

I make especially low `PermGen` to force GC in PermGen during application redeploy, because `PermGen` cleaned only on memory pressure - I decide to monitor if OutOfMemoryError still effects my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things worth looking at.

1. Do you have sufficient PermGen to hold at least 2 instances of your application at the same time? I believe sometimes it takes the Garbage Collector multiple passes to remove all references, so there needs to be some "margin" for one instance being released for GC and another being loaded.
2. Try switching to another Garbage Collector. I have seen situations I can only explain with bugs in the GC and Parallell, CMS and G1 behaves differently in those situations.
3. In case you want to try out an alternative method for finding the GC root path, you can have a look at [this blog series of mine](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/) or [Arit](https://github.com/kszbcss/arit/wiki/GettingStarted).
4. You may also want to see if the problem is resolved by adding my [ClassLoader Leak Prevention Library](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention) to your app. In case it is, watch the logs for the potential reasons.

Comment: Thanks for support! I believe that I fall into case **1**. I
already have thought about making `PermGen` size as **double of app
requirement**. So surprised by your description that GC may fail
due to multi-pass mechanic...

Comment: I had read all your blog series on GC year ago, and task to play
with `classloader-leak-prevention`
 is in my TODO list. But until now I have no
proficiency to hunt leaks, so should re-read you blog again ))

Comment: I hear that Parallel GC have issues with PermGen and considered deprecated for modern hardware. So I always use `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` (and wait while `G1` become generally accepted).